# Make AVFoundation not stop iPod music

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avfoundation

Im using the AVFoundation framework to play sound files. The problem im having is that its stopping music from playing when the audio file gets used, im not saying play both files continuously, but play the sound file, then pick up the ipod music right where it left off. Is there any way i can use AVFoundation is this kind of way? or is there a better framework for it?

Here is what my code looks like:

```
click = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@/Click.WAV", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:click error:nil];
audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 1;
[click release];
[audioPlayer play];
```

This code works completely fine, i had to type it out so ignore any problems that there might be with it.

Thanks,
Jacob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [AVAudioSession](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008240) class to change the audio "category" of your app: thus you can allow it to play on top of the iPod music. Use the `-setCategory:error:` method, and you will probably want to use `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient`. More info can be found in the [Audio Session Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875).

Comment: Okay that seemed to work, but now when i load the app the music gets killed, i can start it back up via multitasking, then try my sound and it works. How do i get it so it doesnt kill the music. heres what i did: `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];` 

PS: This is in my mainviewcontroller

Comment: Did you run that before starting your audio player?

Comment: I ran it after i said [click release];

Comment: Try doing it before you create the audio player, or maybe as soon as the app launches.

Comment: Just got it! i put it before everything